# Random process on ternary string

Tags: time-complexity, proof-techniques, randomized-algorithms, termination

Given a ternary string S of length N, do the following:

- Find the first strictly decreasing pair of digits.
- Randomly change one of the digits in the pair to another value.
- The string is circular (i.e the digit after the last digit is the first digit)
- The program terminates when there is no strictly decreasing pair.

Example: For N = 3 and S = 010

- Iteration 1:

  - 1st decreasing pair of S: 10
  - Change to: 11 (1/4 chance)
  - New S: 011
- Iteration 2:

  - 1st decreasing pair of new S: 10 (the last and first digit)
  - Change to: 12 (1/4 chance)
  - New S: 211
- Iteration 3:

  - 1st decreasing pair of new S: 21
  - Change to: 11
  - New S: 111 **END!**

The rules imply that termination happens if and only if the string is constant. And for N large enough, the program always terminates with 111...111 (experimental).

In reality, the program terminates with linear to quadratic complexity in comparison to N.
I want to rigorously prove this termination and estimate the exact complexity.
**I just want to know what are the possible methods for this kind of problems. I would also appreciate any interesting source that helps or deals with a similar problem.**

I have tried viewing this as an **absorbing Markov chain** where each ternary number is a state and 00...00, 11...11 and 22...22 are my absorbing states. For N small, I can calculate exactly the expect number of iteration through the absorption time vector (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain). And experimental results converge it. However for N large, I don't have any idea how to bound such vector to any polynomial function of N.

Comment: Isn't that a Markov process ?

Comment: Is the "first" to be taken literally after a change, or is it the first that follows/starts at the change ?

Comment: `rigorously prove this termination` assume *every* random change to result in an unlike pair: possible, if becoming increasingly unlikely.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes it is an absorbing Markov chain I believe. I can calculate explicitly the absorption time vector for very small N (and experimental result converges to it!). But for N very large, I don't know how to bound that vector. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain

Comment: @YvesDaoust the first follow/starts at the change